# How to detect/identify M.2 SSD

Tags: ssd, wmic

As you know you can get a list of drives connected via SATA using wmic:

```
wmic diskdrive list
```

This however doesn't seem to work with M.2 SSDs. Is there any equivalent for M.2 SSDs that is not vendor specific?

Comment: have you tried `wmic diskdrive get name, serialnumber, mode` I do not have an M2 but need to snatch one up would love to know this too if it works.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin - nope, not working

Comment: Try this and save it as .bat `@echo off
for /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%n in ('WMIC path Win32_PnPEntity get Name ^| findstr "."') do set PCIExpress_NAME=%%n
echo %PCI Express%
pause` This should display some information on about your SSD im trying to get closer to finding out the possible Serial as I cant find any documentation on it. It does seem as the WMIC does not support PCIE devices.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin this didn't work either

Comment: I've done some research and it looks like no one has achieved this yet I even talked to a colleague he said it was very interesting. So I hope someone has some more knowelge about this because it seems this could get some attention as more people switch to pcie SSD's

Answer (score 8):

In Windows 10 (maybe works in 8 already but definitely not in windows 7) you can use

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\storage path msft_disk get Model,BusType
```

BusType of 17 means NVMe, 11 Sata, 7 USB (full list can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830493(v=vs.85).aspx))

Win 10 based WinPE does also support this but needs additional packages (The classes are part of Windows PowerShell/WinPE-StorageWMI which has [some additional dependencies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference)).